# Delphi Windows 8 Live Tile App: Unable to Deploy a Tile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, live-tile, delphi-xe4

Delphi Live Tile for Windows 8: To create a Live Tile application you have to place a Live Tile component on a Metropolis form, enter the name of a certificate that you have created and the publisher of that certificate. Then you have to update the app manifest and deploy the tile. Every time I do that it tells me that `"no certificates were found that met all the given criteria"` and that it is unable to deploy the tile.

Now, I went through the steps for preparing my environment for a Delphi Metropolis Live Tile app, including creating a self signed certificate, getting a temporary Microsoft developer license and the rest of the steps outlined in Enbarcadero's "Setting up Your Environment for Developing Live Tiles for Metropolis UI." So I have no clue as to what the error message, `"no certificates were found that met all the given criteria"` could possibly mean. Obviously I must have done something wrong as some point but because I can view my certificate and verify the other requirements laid out by Embarcadero, I have no idea where to look for an answer.

Comment: This is a pretty unusual one because TLiveTile, the part we have source code to see, doesn't have much to do with this.  Have you tried installing Visual Studio 2012 express and acquiring a developer license the traditional way instead of the docwiki way which suggests using a powershell command?   

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Setting_Up_Your_Environment_for_Developing_Live_Tiles_for_Metropolis_UI

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I don't see what installing VS 2012 Express gets me. If I attempt to sign the package with the publisher's name which appears in a VS app. it still gives me the same error message. I must be really dense not to see what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: So you get the same error with visual studio express? Now you can go on the microsoft answers site and ask what it means. Now that you're using ONLY THEIR Tool, they should be able to tell you what is wrong.  Do you have any other computer you can try it on?

I would ask your question HERE:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/home?category=visualstudio%2Cvslanguages%2Cvstfs%2Cnetdevelopment%2Cvsarch

Comment: I see what you're saying: that I should develop an app with VS. I don't any error like that with VS. This is still with Delphi. Sorry. My basic problem seems to be that I don't seem to be able to make a certificate that Delphi will recognize so it can deploy a live tiles app. It may, however, be helpful to look at the Microsoft site to see what might be said about signing a app to deploy it.

Comment: No. Haven't you ever troubleshooted before? :-) So you are really not being very clear.   I asked you if you get the same error with visual studio, and you don't. Visual Studio works fine?  Okay, so then the issue may be with the Embarcadero instructions. unfortunately I don't know what to tell you, other than perhaps try over on the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: I admit I do have trouble making myself clear in this matter. I suspect that Embarcadero's documentation is probably flawed. I can find very little information on Windows 8 development using Delphi. Perhaps very few if any developers are using it. Thanks for trying to make sense of the problem, in any case. I think Visual Studio may be a better tool for Live Tile apps than Delphi, so I will go in that direction and mark Delphi as a dead end.

Comment: Delphi can only make a live tile app because it is using a little helper app written probably in C#.  The trick here is that they must then change its signatures so it is authorized to load and run inside the WinRT sandbox, a limit Microsoft forces on everyone. In short, you're using a C#/.net WinRT mini app that does the live tile work, and your Delphi program simply uses an Indy-component to talk to that little "Live tile proxy" app over a local TCP/IP socket.  If you really want a real WinRT app, your only option right now is C#. Embarcadero was left with no other option here.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sounds like Delphi is not a very good tool for developing Live Tile apps. I think I'll grit my teeth and learn to code in C# with Visual Studio.

Comment: If I was trying to add a live tile to my own Delphi based main app I would definitely write it myself using Visual Studio Express. Then I could do whatever I want in there, and even have it open to a metro main-screen if I wanted to, then have it launch my legacy Win32 Desktop app, from that launch-screen.